# List Blobs in Container having 1000+ (large number of files). [AZURE-STORAGE][REST]

Tags: azure, pagination, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-rest-api

I am trying to make a get `List of Blobs in a Container` **REST** call to my Azure storage account.
Currently, I have a limited number of files and the response that I get is in the following format as specified in [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs).:

[image]

But if there are 1000s of files in this container the response will be huge will it still be in the following `XML format` or will there be any pagination or paging?
I can't practically test it for 1000 files and there is no such thing mentioned in the docs here. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is yes. Maximum number of blobs that can be returned in a single list blobs request is 5000 (it can be less than that and even zero).

If more blobs are available, then you’ll get a continuation token which you can use to fetch next set of blobs. This continuation token can be found in  element in response body.

For further reference, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enumerating-blob-resources.

Comment: Can you please share the documentation or reference which has information about continuation token and response in those cases.

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enumerating-blob-resources.